# How to view data when calling a Web Service?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, web-services

I lately haven been progressing through my iOS training, and now I'm attempting to learn about web services. I believe I have the main concept down:

- I make a call to a web service
- I receive data from that web service
- I parse the JSON data
- I now do whatever I want with the data.

Now I have been going through many tutorials on a simple web service example, but they all use table views to populate their data. I don't necessarily want to do that until I'm more experienced. For now, I just want to make a call, get data, and NSLog it. Below is some code I got from the tutorial:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#define WXFORECAST @"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/\
forecast/daily?q=%@&units=Imperial&cnt=7&mode=json"
#define LOCATION @"Fairbanks"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {


    // insert code here...

    // Start the refresh control

    // Create the URL string based on location
    NSString *urlString =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:WXFORECAST, LOCATION];

    // Setup the session
    NSURLSessionConfiguration * configuration =
    [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session =
    [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
    NSURLRequest *request =
    [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL
                                  URLWithString:urlString]];

    // Create a data task to transfer the web service endpoint contents
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask =
    [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
               completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                   NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                   // Stop the refresh control

                   if (error)
                   {

                       return;
                   }

                   // Parse the JSON from the data object
                   NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                         JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

                   // Store off the top level array of forecasts
                   NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                   items = json[@"list"];

                   }];

    // Start the data task
    [dataTask resume];

}
return 0;
}
```

Now saying I don't know what this code is an understatement. I'm at a loss for words when I see this. I believe this code is making a call, but now I want to NSLog the data from that web service. It seems like an easy enough answer, but I've been getting frustrated for the past couple of hours over this.

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can just use `NSLog` to show the response, e.g., `NSLog(@"%@", json);`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to doing NSLog as bobnoble suggested above, if you put a breakpoint after the following line of code is executed - you can print out the contents of the NSDictionary in the debugger.

```
      NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                     JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

In the example code that you have above you would type in 'po json' (without the single quotes) - and that would output the entire dictionary.